# Why 'blocked by CORS policy' in React, but not with Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

Running the exact same script in React is blocked by Cors policy, but not when I run it with node.

1. Why can it be done with node, but not with React?
2. How can I still fetch this in a React app?
3. It's also allowed in [this chrome extension](https://github.com/elias94/youtube-subtitles-viewer), is that because the script is executed visiting youtube so that domain is youtube?

```
async function isThisAllowed() {
    const videoURL = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnQe0xW_JY4`
    const data = await axios.get(videoURL);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS is a way for websites (in this case YouTube) to prevent other domains from accessing them. Basically, in this case, scripts running on other domains **will not be able to access `youtube.com`.**

CORS is only enforced by browsers, so it makes sense that your Node script would work as expected while your React app wouldn't.

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) a good explanation of how CORS works.

You could fix this with a simple Node proxy:

```
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();

app.get("/proxy", async (req, res) => {
  const resp = await axios.get(req.query.url);

  res.send(resp.data);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: Nice, is than a solution to scrape from a node server and then serve that data to the react part on the client side? Would you run a server and client? are there good tutorials for this? I'll also google this, thanks

Comment: Yep! You could throw together a simple Node proxy to get it working; I've updated my answer with a basic example.

Comment: Nice, I got a working! I did it with react and adding "proxy" to the package.json of the react app refering to the localhost of the server (express). I got the proxy from this article: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-setup-nodejs-express-for-react/